# How to add a timestamp of a prepared stmt to mysql database when code is run?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp, prepared-statement

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username,created) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['username-reg','whatdoiputhere?']);
$stmt->execute();
```

I want to add a "now" date/timestamp that can also be inserted simultaneously so that i can keep track of when users create accounts. is there a function that i need to write/reference to get the current date? or is there an already known function that i just need to reference? i am new to php, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOW()` :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username,created) VALUES (?, NOW())");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['username-reg']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage MySQL's [timestamp initialization feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

This works by adding a `timestamp` column to the table with the `default current_timestamp` option:

```
create table users (
    user_id int primary key auto_increment,
    username varchar(50),
    ts_created timestamp default current_timestamp
);
```

With this set-up in place, you don't have to worry about that column anymore. Just ignore it when you insert, and the database will automatically set it as needed:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['username-reg']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Note: if you also want the timestamp to be updated when the record is *modified*, you can add the `on update current_timestamp` to the definition of the column.